# Trace map from $H^1$ into $H^{\frac 12}$, does this statement imply another?

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, trace

Consider trace map $T:H^1(\Omega) \to H^{\frac 12}(\partial\Omega)$ on a sufficiently smooth domain $\Omega$. It has a partial inverse $E$.

If we have the statement 
$$F(u,Eu) = 0\quad\text{for all $u \in H^{\frac 12}(\partial\Omega)$}$$
does this imply 
$$F(Tv,v) = 0\quad\text{for all $v \in H^{1}(\Omega)$}?$$

---

We do know that $T(H^1) = H^{\frac 12}$. So it seems like this result should be true. Here $F$ is just some weak formulation so some integral over $\Omega$ and $\partial\Omega$. For concretness take
$$F(u,Eu) = \int_\Omega \nabla w \nabla Eu + \int_{\partial\Omega}w u$$
for $w \in H^1(\Omega)$ fixed.

Comment: Sorry, what is $F$?

Comment: @wisher It is just some weak formulation, i.e. integrals over $\Omega$ and $\partial\Omega$ involving the arguments.

Comment: $F$ can be anything, as its stand in your question, so the answer is no. I think it is better to state the problem, with these integrals that you mentioned in the comment.

Comment: @Tomás please see now.

Comment: Can you defines $E$ please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not true, even for this particular $F$. To see it, let $Q:H^1_0(\Omega)\to\mathbb{R}$ be the linear functional, defined by

$$Q\phi=\int_\Omega \nabla w\nabla \phi.$$

If $w\neq 0$ then, the image of $Q$ is $\mathbb{R}$. Therefore, there is $v\in H_0^1(\Omega)$ such that $Qv\neq 0$. Note that for this particular $v$, we have that $Tv=0$, because $v\in H_0^1(\Omega)$. We must conclude that $$\int_\Omega\nabla w\nabla v\neq 0=\int_{\partial\Omega}w Tv.$$